# Combining two columns in Datatables Server-side

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to combine two columns (covered_from and covered_to) data in my datatables. Here is my code:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'employee_number', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'employee_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'leave_type', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 
        'db' => 'covered_from', 
        'dt' => 3, 
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row) {
            $from = $row['covered_from'];            
            $from = date('F d, Y', strtotime($from));
            return $from;
        }
    ),
    array( 
        'db' => 'covered_to', 
        'dt' => 4, 
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row) {
            $to = $row['covered_to'];     
            if(empty($to) || $to == "Halfday") {
                $to = "";
            }
            return $to;
        }
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'reason', 'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'number_of_days', 'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cutoff', 'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'status', 'dt' => 8 ),
);
```

The result should be like this,

```
array( 
        'db' => 'covered_from', 
        'dt' => 3, 
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row) {
            $from = $row['covered_from'];
            $to= $row['covered_to'];
            
            $from = date('F d, Y', strtotime($from));
            $to = date('F d, Y', strtotime($to));

            return $from . " - " .$to;
        }
    ),
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already solved my problem by adding these codes I've found in the internet.

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return data + " - " +row[4];
                },
                "targets": 3
            },
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 4 ] }
        ],
```

Thanks!